# declare hashmap in javascript with <String,String array>

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I want to declare a hashmap in javascript with `<String, String array>` instead of `<String,Integer>`. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to use a javascript Array object, be aware that an array index can only be accessed via integers.

```
var arr = [];
arr['person'] = 'John Smith';

alert(arr.length); // returns 0, not an array anymore;
```

and

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = 'John Smith';

alert(arr.length); // returns 1, still an array;
```

The above would work in javascript, but `var arr` actually is not an array object anymore. You cannot sort it, for example.

So for you hashmap you could do

```
var map = new Object();

map['person'] = [];
map['person']['test'] = 'myvalue';
map['person']['test2'] = 'myvalue2';

alert(map['person']['test']);
```

Comment: You'd better use `var arr = {};`

Comment: You'd better not use `new Object()`, it's not as optimized as `{}` (I know, micro-optimizations are not worth the hassle) and someone might have overridden `Object`.